# Please suggest to setup the live paypal accounts for split payment in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using PaypalAdaptivePayment for chained payment. 
I have used

```
 gem "active_paypal_adaptive_payment"
```

My adaptive payment settings as below.

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :live

ADAPTIVE_PAYMENT_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalAdaptivePayment.new({
                                                                :login => ACTIVEMERCHANT_CONFIG[:username],
                                                                :password => ACTIVEMERCHANT_CONFIG[:password],
                                                                :signature => ACTIVEMERCHANT_CONFIG[:signature],
                                                                :appid => ACTIVEMERCHANT_CONFIG[:application_id]})
```

application id is generated as the Live AppId from a test app created in `https://apps.paypal.com/user/my-account/applications/manage`

I have set in configurations for admin account as the live account email for paypal.com

But while doing transaction it shows the error,

```
User is not allowed to perform this action
```

after google I found that my app is  "conditionally approved", yes it shows in status also.

Is this the correct way to set up the app, or i need any changes in settings?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you upgraded your account to a business account and it looks like the error you are receiving is in relation to not having the permission to run on a particular account. This error will sometimes show on a Premier account that has not yet been upgraded to a Business account.

Comment: If your application uses certain advanced operations, PayPal Conditionally approves your application and issues an AppID within two business days an after that you can use that APP ID into your application.